# Вывод данных из таблицы

Tags: android, java, sqlite

Здравствуйте. Разрабатываю приложения под *Android*, для работы с БД использую *SQLite*.

Возникла такая проблема:
Нужно вывести таблицу с 2-мя полями (то бишь считать данные из таблицы и вывести их на экран). На экране это должно выглядеть, как прокручиваемый список или прокручиваемая таблица (под словом "прокручиваемая" подразумеваю, что ее можно листать. Вниз, вверх...)

Как можно это реализовать?

*P.S. поджимают сроки, спасите, пожалуйста :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

здесь все очень похоже:
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/111-urok-52-simplecursoradapter-primer-ispolzovanija.html

Comment: Благодарю. По-моему, то, что нужно. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: можно ли увидеть готовый пример ?

Answer (score -1):

Вот статья на английском [ссылка](http://fundroiding.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/android-listview-with-multiple-string-arrays-using-simple-adapter/)
Достаточно просто и удобно.